# Looping through all the rows only returns the last one

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, oracle-apex, return-value

I'm trying to return a value into an Apex page item  with this Plsql.
The page item source is PL/SQL Function Body.

```
DECLARE
v_val VARCHAR2 (3000 CHAR);
  CURSOR c_mylist
  IS
  select * from table_mylist
  order by id;
  BEGIN
  FOR r_mylist IN c_mylist
  LOOP
   --dbms_output.put_line( c_mylist.item );
   v_val := c_mylist.item ||' '||c_mylist.item;
  END LOOP;
  return v_val;
END;
```

Unexpectedly it only returns the last value of the cursor into the page item and not all the row values.
A try with dbms_output.put_line in the SQL Developer shows the correct result.
What is going wrong with my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should have been

```
v_val := v_val ||' '||c_mylist.item;
```

instead of

```
v_val := c_mylist.item ||' '||c_mylist.item;
```

---

Though, instead of that whole PL/SQL code, you could have used a single `select` statement:

```
declare
  v_val varchar2(3000);
begin
  select listagg(item, ' ') within group (order by id)
    into v_val
    from table_mylist;
  return v_val;
end;
```